# D3 Geo Projection plugin cannot find module 'fs'

Tags: node.js, d3.js, reactjs, d3.geo

I'm trying to display a D3 geo projection in a React component.

When viewing any page, this error happens inside the D3 Geo projection module:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'readFileSync'

It is thrown at this line in the module's index.js:

```
module.exports = new Function("d3", 
  fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "d3.geo.projection.js"), "utf-8"));
```

Here are the modules added to the `package.json` as dependencies:

```
"d3": "^3.5.16",
"d3-geo-projection": "^0.2.16",
"topojson": "^1.6.25"
```

The following is the code for my `GeoMap` React component using D3 geo projection plugin:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var d3 = require("d3");

require("d3-geo-projection")(d3);

var d3GeoMap = {};

d3GeoMap.create = function(el, props, state) {
    var svg = d3.select(el).append("svg")
        .attr("class", "geoChart")
        .attr("width", props.width)
        .attr("height", props.height);

    this.update(el, state);
};

d3GeoMap.update = function(el, state) {
    d3.select(el).select("svg").append("rect")
        .data(state.data)
        .enter()
        .attr("class", "map")
        .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));
};

var GeoMap = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        data: React.PropTypes.object
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        var el = this.refs.geoRoot;
        d3GeoMap.create(el,
            {
                width: 900,
                height: 900
            },
            {
                data: this.props.data
            });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (<div ref="geoRoot"></div>);
    }
});

module.exports = GeoMap;
```

**NOTE:** This error happens when hitting any page, even ones that do not use my `GeoMap` component.

Does anyone have insight on why the D3 Geo Projection plugin cannot find the 'fs' module?

Comment: what bundler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Webpack along with Babel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require("d3-geo-projection")` when bundled assumes that `fs.readFileSync` is replaced with the actual code which for example in browserify is done with the [brfs transform](https://github.com/substack/brfs)

However the index.js file is just doing the following

```
module.exports = function (d3) {
  // all the code of ./d3.geo.projection.js is included here
}
```

Therefore if you're not using a bundler with this transform use this instead

```
var d3 = require("d3");
// assumes that d3 is already defined here
require("d3-geo-projection/d3.geo.projection")
```

Comment: Thanks!! This did the trick.  To clarify how this worked for me though, I placed the suggested code block into my react component, AND REMOVED `module.exports = new Function("d3", 
  fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "d3.geo.projection.js"), "utf-8"));` from the D3 Geo Projection's `index.js` file.